# how to transform response for $resource

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

hey guys I am new to trying $resource(always used $q) and I have been banging my head with this issue for a bit and was looking for some help!

so heres my factory below

```
.factory('Location', ['$resource', 'ENV',

  function($resource, ENV) {

return $resource(ENV.API_URL + 'locations/:id', 
                {}, 
                {
                 'query': {
                    method: 'GET',
                    // transformResponse: function (data) {
                    //   console.log(data);
                    //   return data;
                    // },
                    isArray: false 
                  }
                });
}]);
```

my response looks like

```
{  
   "meta":{  
      "code":200
   },
   "data":[  
      {  
         "id":1,
         "name":"Test"
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "name":"Test2"
      }
   ]
}
```

in my controller I have

```
$scope.locations = Location.query();
```

and finally my html

```
<ul class="list">
    <li class="item" ng-repeat="location in locations">
      <a href="{{location.link}}">
        {{location.name}}
      </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I cannot for the life of me get query to grab the 'data' from the json and iterate through it for the ng-repeat. I am assuming I have to transform the response somehow but cannot figure it out.

Comment: Have you tries `location in locations.data`?

Comment: @Chandermani yeah I did that and ... oh wow my <pre> tags were pushing down the list the whole time and I didn't notice to scroll... IM SO DUMB